# Не выходит переименовать файл базы данных

Tags: android, android-file

При попытке переименовать файл базы данных через:

```
File databaseFile = ((ChoiceDictionary) getActivity()).getDatabasePath(dictionary);
File oldDatabaseFile = new File(databaseFile.getParentFile(), dictionaryName);
databaseFile.renameTo(oldDatabaseFile);
```

Создается второй файл (с таким же содержимым) и остается старый. Как просто переименовать, а не создать новый?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по гуглу и en-SO, если ваш код не работает, то просто дополните его удалением старого файла после создания нового.

Удалять файл просто:

```
databaseFile.delete();
```

---

Также можно попробовать использовать не то, что из контекста возвращается, а создать новый объект `File`:

```
File from = new File(((ChoiceDictionary) getActivity()).getDatabasePath(dictionary).getAbsolutePath());
File to = new File(from.getParentFile(), dictionaryName);
from.renameTo(to);
```

Comment: А чем принципиально отличается Ваш подход от моего? И почему происходит копирование (в моем случае), а не переименование?

Comment: А мой подход решил проблему?

Comment: Еще не попробовал, за компьютер сяду не раньше,  чем через час.

Comment: Я не знаю, будет ли результат от мною предложенного кода, но я бы, столкнувшись с такой проблемой, именно так бы попробовал, ибо такие примеры видел на enSO

Comment: Попробовал... Как и у меня — создается второй.

Comment: А чем мой и Ваш код отличается от обычного копирования? И как я уже спрашивал: почему происходит создание второго файла?

Comment: Кстати, вместе с БД, копируется и файл имя_БД.db-journal. Но почему???

Comment: Код по сути ничем не отличается. Своим кодом я просто проверил бы - а вдруг?.. Также, возможно, проблема в незакрытом доступе к базе данных. Попробуйте базу закрыть, а потом копировать. Если не поможет - просто удаляйте старый файл после создания нового. имя_БД.db-journal откуда - хз. Мне вообще не понятно зачем фам базу данных так переименовывать...

Comment: Ну надо :). Эх... Ладно, добавьте в ответ, как удалить старый файл и скопировать старый, с новым именем, я приму ответ. И еще, ``renameTo`` — не нужно?

Comment: Почему renameTo() не нужно?..

Comment: Ну а смысл, если файл и так создается с новым именем, а `renameTo` ничего не переименовывает?

Comment: Скорее всего без вызова renameTo инфа из старого файла в новый не скопируется, а создастся просто пустой файл.

Comment: А не странный ли подход? Ни разу не видел, чтобы копировали через `renameTo`... Можно скопировать файл не через ж... `renameTo`, а нормально? =)

Comment: Не знаю, можно ли (скорее всего да) скопировать "обычным" способом. Скорее всего дело тут в том, что вы базу данных пытаетесь перименовать. Попробуйте ваш код на обычных файлах. Судя по гуглу с обычными файлами этот код работает.

Comment: С обычными-то работает... А есть способ переименовать БД? Я задавал тут такой вопрос, но из ответов были только переименовать файл (что я и делал) и попросту все скопировать из одной БД в другую (что затратно для переименования...).

Comment: Судя по enSO, нема способа переименовать базу данных кроме переименования файла, а это требует, как мы выяснили, удаление файла старой БД. Жизнь - боль, такие дела(

Comment: Ладно, копирование вынесу в отдельный поток (если пользователь введет 1000+ записей, программа может подвиснуть) и попробую без скопировать `renameTo` (а вдруг прокатит, глаза сильно режет :))). Но есть еще один вопрос: как называется кружочек, который обозначает, что идет загрузка (во время копировании и загрузке БД нельзя давать трогать `Activity` пользователю), для этого нужно показать загрузку?

Comment: Чтобы запретить пользовать активити вызовите перед запуском задачи ProgressDialog c setCanceled(false);

Comment: Сейчас попробую. И `renameTo` все-таки ничего не делает :(.